# How to remove noise after reading a raw image file using np.fromfile() method

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, hough-transform

I got to know RAW images are interleaved and each pixel holds the value of each R,G,B component. So I have written below code to read the RGB pixel values and reshaped the image array to make it RGB image. After then I am converting the image to a binary one to process further. After conversion when I am trying to display the image it seems to contains noise. Can anyone help me in removing the noise?

Python version: 3.6

CODE:

```
from scipy import misc
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from PIL import Image
import rawpy
import imageio

def convert_to_binary(img):
    threshold = 150
    img[img <= 30] = 0
    img[img > 30] = 255
    return img

def sobel_test(im):
    dx = ndimage.sobel(im, 0)  # horizontal derivative
    dy = ndimage.sobel(im, 1)  # vertical derivative
    mag = np.hypot(dx, dy)  # magnitude
    print(np.max(mag))
    mag *= 255.0 / np.max(mag)  # normalize (Q&D)
    print(mag)
    misc.imsave('sobel.jpg', mag)
    return mag


A = np.fromfile("ABC.raw", dtype='int8', sep="")
A = np.reshape(A, (756, 1008, 3))
print("A.shape: %d", A.shape)
print("A: ", A)
print("A[0]: ", A[0])
img_gray = np.dot(A[..., :3], [0.30, 0.59, 0.11])
print("img_gray :", img_gray)
print("img_gray shape: ", img_gray.shape)
print("img_gray size: ", img_gray.size)

sob_img = sobel_test(img_gray)
binary_img = convert_to_binary(sob_img)
plt.imshow(binary_img, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

INPUT RAW Image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12LcQZyYWMg9_6T_n3gjy7kBadRGNMDdr

Output Image

[image]